# the correct order of reference when deleting tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have just read this:

> DROP TABLE commands must be in the correct order of reference

Does it mean that if I have the tables in the database: TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3,
then I can't write a script in which I would drop tables in the order: DROP TABLE2, DROP TABLE3, DROP TABLE1, but instead I would have to follow the pattern 1,2,3??

Comment: DROP TABLE tablename CASCADE? (Beware, lots of things may get lost...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can You post a link to source of this quote?

I think, what they mean are corect order of references between tables e.g. foregin keys. You cannot just drop table while another one have columns with foregin key referencing columns from dropped table.

So, if we have table A with primary key A.id and table B with pk B.id and foreigin key B.id_A referencing A.id, and table C with pk C.id and foreign key C.id_B referencing B.id, the correct order of reference should be:

```
DROP C;
DROP B;
DROP A;
```

Of course You have other options in oracle for example [cascade constrains](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables010.htm#ADMIN01505). And in Postgres You can for example use [defer constrains](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-constraints.html). I am not sure about MSSQL server options in that matter.

Comment: thanks for the comment, you might be right. unfortunately, I can't post the source